# How to copy datatypes between excel sheets

Tags: excel

Probably a stupid question

I have two sheets, with multiple columns

How do I copy the datatypes from one sheet to the other?

For example if one sheets columns have the following datatypes:
General, Date, Currency, Number,

But the second has
General, General, General, General,

How can i copy the first sheets datatypes to the second one without changin any data under the columns, just changing their type?

Comment: Those are number formats, not data types. Either use Format Painter, or Copy/PasteSpecial Formats.

Comment: I’m hoping for the number formats to be applied to all rows under said columns